# Difference between Kernel Virtual Address and Kernel Logical Address?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am not able to exactly difference between kernel logical address and virtual address. In Linux device driver book it says that all logical address are kernel virtual address, and virtual address doesn't have any linear mapping. But logically wise when we say it is logical and when we say virtual and in which situation we use these two ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Linux kernel maps most of the virtual address space that belongs to the kernel to perform 1:1 mapping with an offset of the first part of physical memory. (slightly less then for 1Gb for 32bit x86, can be different for other processors or configurations). For example, for kernel code on x86 address 0xc00000001 is mapped to physical address 0x1.

This is called logical mapping - a 1:1 mapping (with an offset) that allows the kernel to access most of the physical memory of the machine.

But this is not enough - sometime we have more then 1Gb physical memory on a 32bit machine, sometime we want to reference non contiguous physical memory blocks as contiguous to make thing simple, sometime we want to map memory mapped IO regions which are not RAM.

For this, the kernel keeps a region at the top of its virtual address space where it does a "random" page to page mapping. The mapping there do not follow the 1:1 pattern of the logical mapping area. This is what we call the virtual mapping.

It is important to add that on many platforms (x86 is an example), both the logical and virtual mapping are done using the same hardware mechanism (TLB controlling virtual memory). In many cases, the "logical mapping" is actually done using virtual memory facility of the processor, so this can be a little confusing. The difference therefore is the pattern according to which the mapping is done: 1:1 for logical, something random for virtual.

Comment: Hi, I have a confusion: on a system with 512MB physical RAM, all 512MB are 1:1 mapped to 3GB ~ 3GB + 512MB kernel logical space, no high memory. Now kernel wants to access virtual address 3GB + 0x10000, which is directly mapped to physical address 0x10000, what if this physical frame has already been used (e.g. by a user process), what would happen?

Comment: does this logical mapping actually go through (translated by) page table like other virtual address access?

Answer (score 24):

Basically there are 3 kinds of addressing, namely

1. Logical Addressing : Address is formed by base and offset. This is nothing but segmented addressing, where the address (or offset) in the program is always used with the base value in the segment descriptor
2. Linear Addressing : Also called virtual address. Here adresses are contigous, but the physical address are not. Paging is used to implement this.
3. Physical addressing : The actual address on the Main Memory!

Now, in linux, Kernel memory (in address space) is beyond 3 GB ( 3GB to 4GB), i.e. 0xc000000..The addresses used by Kernel are not Physical addresses. To map the virtual address it uses PAGE_OFFSET. Care must be taken that no page translation is involved. i.e. these addresses are contiguous in nature. However there is a limit to this, i.e. 896 MB on x86. Beyond which paging is used for translation. When you use vmalloc, these addresses are returned to access the allocated memory.

In short, when someone refers to Virtual Memory in context of User Space, then it is through Paging. If Kernel Virtual Memory is mentioned then it is either PAGE_OFFSETed or vmalloced address.

(Reference - Understanding Linux Kernel - 2.6 based )

Shash

Answer (score 10):

Kernel logical addresses are mappings accessible to kernel code through normal CPU memory access functions. On 32-bit systems, only 4GB of kernel logical address space exists, even if more physical memory than that is in use. Logical address space backed by physical memory can be allocated with `kmalloc`.

Virtual addresses do not necessarily have corresponding logical addresses. You can allocate physical memory with `vmalloc` and get back a virtual address that has no corresponding logical address (on 32-bit systems with PAE, for example). You can then use `kmap` to assign a logical address to that virtual address.

Answer (score 2):

Simply speaking, virtual address would include "high memory", which doesn't do the 1:1 mapping for the physical address,if your RAM size is more than the address range of kernel(typically,For 1G/3G in X86,your RAM is 3G but your kernel addressing range is 1G) and also the address return from kmap() and vmalloc(), which requires the kernel to establish page table for the memory mapping. since logic address is always memory mapped by the kernel(1:1 mapping), you don't need to explicitly call kernel API,like set_pte to set up the page table entry for the particular page.

so virtual address can't be logic address all the time.